# console-setup hangs when installing with package manager in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Trying to do an upgrade on an Ubuntu machine I inherited from someone, and it hangs whenever it has to configure console-setup. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best thing to do is to find out what command it's running. You can do this by editing the post-install script. Edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/console-setup.post-inst and add

```
set -x
```

as the second line, just after the

```
#!/bin/bash
```

line.

Now run

```
# dpkg --configure --pending
```

and you should be able to see what command it is running. This should give you a better clue what to fix.

If you can not work out how to fix it, you can place

```
exit 0
```

on the second line of the post-install script, run the dpkg command again and the package will install without doing the configure stage, which may leave your system broken, so only do this if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my kernel fixed it